# Not getting results from cloud functions by .where()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using this code to get data from a collection by comparing

```
/* eslint-disable */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.checkForPending = functions.pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun(async (context) 
=> {
   var currentTime = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
   var total; //getting time from firebase server
    var firebase_time = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(); // {'_seconds': 123456, 
_nanoseconds: 123000000}
    // Convert map of nanoseconds and seconds to milliseconds
    var firebase_seconds_to_milliseconds = firebase_time._seconds * 1000; // 123456000
    var firebase_nanoseconds_to_milliseconds = Math.round(firebase_time._nanoseconds / 
1000000) //123
    var milliseconds = firebase_seconds_to_milliseconds + 
firebase_nanoseconds_to_milliseconds;
    var firebase_month = firebase_time.toDate().getMonth();

    var unix_to_date_before_buffer = new Date(milliseconds); 
    var unix_to_date_after_buffer = new Date(milliseconds);
    // var unix_to_date = new Date(total);
     unix_to_date_before_buffer.setSeconds(0); //coverted from 6:38:23 to 6:38:00
     unix_to_date_after_buffer.setSeconds(0);
     unix_to_date_after_buffer.setMinutes(unix_to_date_after_buffer.getMinutes() + 1);//coverted from 6:38:23 to 6:39:00
  //Want to edit month in this timestamp;
  const query = 
database.collection("users").doc('IELTS').collection('IELTS').where("next", '>=', unix_to_date_before_buffer).where("next", '<=', unix_to_date_after_buffer); // comparing here
 const snapshot = await query.get();
 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data().name),
    queryTest2 = database.collection('rest');
    queryTest2.add(
    {
    'executed': true,
    'name': doc.data().name
    }
    )
  });

  return null;
});
```

The am not getting any results in the console. I am wondering why?
I didn't see any new collection 'rest' formed.
The time in the collection of parameter 'next' was 6:38:24 in the collection in the example.

What I am trying to build -
I am making an app for an institute. I am registering users and making a collection which looks like -
[collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XdXB.png)
(here 'date' is the date of registration and 'next' is the time when The pay will automatically change to 0 because of the starting of next month.)
Now I am running a cloud function that is checking every day if 'next' is equal to the current time of server, then I want to execute something (add a user to a new collection called 'pending'.) and update 'next' to the next month. which should look like this -
[edited-paramter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VLYq.png)

Comment: You should only use `admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()` as a token for inserting a server timestamp into a document *and no other reason*.  You should also not reach into its private members - that is not supported and could break in the future.  If you want to work with the current time as reckoned by the server instance your code is running on, you should just use the normal JavaScript `Date.now()`.

Comment: Also there is not enough information here that we can use to help you.  We can't see the exact data in your documents, and we can't see the values of the variables you're using in your query, so we don't know if they don't actually match up the way you expect.  Your question needs to have enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the behavior you observe.

Comment: Lastly, you are ignoring the promises returned by `add()`, which means none of that async work might complete before the function is actually terminated.

Comment: My field of interest is 'next'
I am checking every minute if the timestamp in 'next' is equal to the current time stamp then I want to update the 'next' in the same document with a updated value. Please help me.

Comment: Please re-read my comments.  There's not enough information in your question.  I suggest also reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How can I show you my data in the documents?

Comment: A screenshot of the document in the Firebase console typically works fine for that.

Comment: Please check again.